# how is this boolean value change

Tags: c

```
// c program to represent boolean values

#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    _Bool boolvar=0;
    int i;

    printf("the value of _Bool is");

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        printf("boolvar=%i\n",boolvar);
        boolvar++;
    }
    printf("\n");

    for (i=5;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("boolvar=%i\n",boolvar);
        boolvar--;
    }
}
```

I made this program and get `1 1 1 1 1` for my first loop and `10101` for second loop. Why does this boolean value fluctuate in second loop while I get only 11111 in first?

Comment: sorry in first loop actually it is boolvar++ not boolvar--

Comment: please edit this so its reflected in the question

Comment: Decrementing a _Bool value in C++ doesn't appear to be defined, which means the behavior you're seeing is likely to be (very) dependent on your C compiler: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec

Answer (score 0):

A now-deprecated feature of the ++ operator in versions of C++ prior to C++ 17 was to set a Boolean value to true; This appears to be what is happening in your first loop (after you fixed it). The -- operator doesn't appear to be officially defined for Boolean values, but I'm guessing the second loop your C compiler is simply using the parity (even vs. odd) of an underlying integer-like type to decide whether the Boolean value is true or false. See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec

Answer (score 0):

For boolean incrementing is similar to a or operation being performed so every time it is one.

While decrementing bool in second loop first time print will be 1
Next 1-1 = 0
Next 0-1 = -1 (Since bool is a single byte and no sign bit it will ignore the sign) so it will again print 1
This goes on for the loop

Hope i gave you the answer